# Let $R_n$ be the number of ways to place $n$ undistinguishable rooks peacefully on an $n×n$ chessboard .Find $R_n$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $R_n$ be the number of ways to place $n$ undistinguishable rooks peacefully on an $n×n$ chessboard . Moreover,  let $H_n,Q_n,M_n,D_n$ be the number  of those placings which are invariant with respect to a half turn, quarter turn , reflection at a distance and reflection at diagonals . Find formulas for $R_n,H_n,Q_n$  and find the recursion for $M_n,D_n$.

The 1st part is quite obvious i.e the number of ways of placing $ n$ tooks such that they are non attacking in an $n×n$ chessboard is $R_n=n!$ .But what does they mean by "number  of those placings which are invariant with respect to a half turn, quarter turn , reflection at a distance and reflection at diagonals ." I am not getting it?...I also need a detailed solution for it....

Comment: @Arthur That is what I'm asking...

Comment: Right. I guess I just got hung up on that one and didn't read the rest of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of examples to clarify the question (I hope).

An 8 by 8 chessboard with non-attacking rooks which is invariant with repect to a half turn (rotation by $180$ degrees):

```
 . . . X . . . .
 X . . . . . . .
 . . X . . . . .
 . X . . . . . .
 . . . . . . X .
 . . . . . X . .
 . . . . . . . X
 . . . . X . . .
```

An 8 by 8 chessboard with non-attacking rooks which is invariant under reflection about the diagonal from the upper left corner to the lower right corner of the board:

```
 . . X . . . . .
 . . . X . . . .
 X . . . . . . .
 . X . . . . . .
 . . . . X . . .
 . . . . . . X .
 . . . . . X . .
 . . . . . . . X
```

However, I do not know what is meant by "reflection at a distance". Maybe reflection about the horizontal or vertical axis through the center of the board?

Comment: Thanks a lot! But i just need to verify that by " rotating it by $180^{\circ}$ " it necessarily means that by rotating let's say...ur first figure by $180^{\circ}$ it remains the same ..is this meant by it?

Comment: @Franklin Yes, that's what they mean by "invariant".